# Hiding a stream in rtc source control stopped working

Tags: rtc

To hide a stream in RTC I change the owner of the stream to the 'team1' and visibilty of the stream to 'team1'. This seems to work until I customise the team area. So once I customise the team area the stream is no longer hidden.

Since by default the team uses the process inherited from the team area's parent, is there extra config I need to add so as to hide the stream ?

EDIT : I think this could be a glitch that occurred as part of an upgrade between RTC3 and RTC4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one article on RTC(4) for RTC resource access control is called:
"[Controlling access to source control in Rational Team Control](https://jazz.net/library/article/215)"

The section "[Use permissions to control access to streams](https://jazz.net/library/article/215#share_workspace)" (RTC3.0.1+) repeats what you did (stream visibility and ownership), but also adds:

> Create a private component in the stream:

- In the stream editor, click the New button beside the component list. In the editor give the name the component Flux Capacitor 2.
- Save the editor.
- Make the component private by selecting Flux Capacitor 2 and clicking on the Change Owner button.
- In the ownership dialog, expand JUnit Project and select Flux Capacitor Tiger Team. Visibility is limited by checking the Restrict to members of this team area and its child team areas

[image: Private component]

So make sure your components are private as well in your setup, and see if that resists better to an RTC4 upgrade (since you can have a working RTC3 client with an RTC4 server)

Comment: thanks, i accept your answer but I repeated the process for a new team area, restricting based on visibility (same as RTC3 setup) and it worked

Comment: @user470184 so there could be a glitch indeed, for an old team area now managed by an RTC4...